# How can i execute several mpd mpc commands simultaneously?

Tags: apache, audio-player, mpd

To control mpd(music player daemon) i use mpc(cusic clayer client). I want to empty queue, add file and play it, using my php-file:

```
exec('/usr/bin/mpc clear');
sleep(1);
exec('/usr/bin/mpc add file.mp3');
sleep(1);
exec('/usr/bin/mpc play');
```

I need something, like:

```
exec('/usr/bin/mpc clear & add file.mp3 & play');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec('/usr/bin/mpc clear & mpc add file.mp3 & mpc play');
```